# Executing a function when key combination is pressed

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I'm adding some functionality to a menubar app. I want to execute a few lines of code that copies some text to the clipboard when a combination of keys are pressed (e.g. cmd + alt + L). This should work globally, i.e any time these keys are pressed.

Not sure how to go about doing this, I tried overriding the keyDown method but it gives an error in AppDelegate.swift saying that there's no method to override.

Comment: FYI, your delegate is likely just an NSObject subclass (so not an NSResponder), which is why there's no keyDown to override.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First step** you need to add a global monitor.

```
NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown, handler: {
    self.keyDown(with: $0)
})
```

But it can be also your func.

**Second step** is to handle these three keys

Read flags from `NSApp.currentEvent?.modifierFlags` and check if they contain `.option` and `.command` flags

**Example**

```
guard let flags = NSApp.currentEvent?.modifierFlags else {
   return
}
let optionKeyIsPressed = flags.contains(.option)
```

At last key you can read from `NSEvent` property `keyCode`.

The keyCode of later "L" you can read from `kVK_ANSI_L`

Hope it's all that you need to solve your problem, good luck.

Comment: Where exactly would you put this global monitor, in its own function in AppDelegate or somewhere else?

Comment: applicationDidFinishLaunching in AppDelegate

Comment: By the way, this code when put in AppDelegate won't work since it's not an NSResponder, would you have to switch it to that type of class first or just add keyDown yourself? Not sure if you can do the latter or what the declaration would even look like

Comment: Sorry for my absence. Not sure what is the problem. Example of AppDelegate for you [link](http://ideone.com/vakWmW)

Comment: Sorry once again for belated aswer and not clear instruction.

Comment: I tried this but even with the exact code using only the option key as a check, my code doesn't run. Any ideas why this might not work? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you give me code of the whole class where you implement it?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/Hw08Pd89

foo() is the function with the relevant code, everything else shouldn't matter but left it in in case.

Comment: try read flags from NSApp.currentEvent instead of event passed in argument.

Comment: Remember that function `foo()` will be called only if key is pressed. So try combining pressing option flag with some key, for example "a". If you need only calling function after pressing options, change the `.keyDown `statement in monitor to `.flagsChanged`

Comment: Changing it to .flagsChanged worked, thanks!

I did try with an example letter but with UInt16(kVK_ANSI_L), xcode threw an error with your code 'use of unresolved identifier kVK_ANSI_L'.